# Laravel get input data from POST request in a rest api

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

i'm trying to get input data which i post them from rest api as an json format, but in laravel i can't get them on controller and that return empty array of request

my api route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'namespace' => 'Api\v1'], function () {
    $this->post('login', 'ApiController@login');
});
```

and `ApiController`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class ApiController extends Controller
{

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
    }
}
```

output:

```
[]
```

ScreenShot

[image: Laravel get input data from POST request in a rest api]

Comment: show your post code

Comment: @GauravGupta post updated

Comment: Try to dump $request by dd($request) and check there is data in $request? @Mahdi.Pishguy

Comment: @ChiragPatel `dd($request->all());` return `[]`

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved by adding this line:

```
Content-type: text/json
```

to RestClient header

Answer (score 0):

use Input Facade class In my case it was work
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

$request = Input::All();